# Does Ubuntu limit connections?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I want to use a torrent to download some files and on my Windows laptop I can get speeds of 1.4mbps (on average), the same was true when I had Windows on this desktop machine. However now I am trying to download using Ubuntu (using Vuze, though I did try using Transmission) and am only getting speeds of 140kbps max. Also no matter what torrent I try it never connects to more than 3 seeds. The port is open (used three checks) and is routed to this Ubuntu machine. I was wondering if Ubuntu limits connections?

Comment: No it doesn't on its own, but your firewalls might and your ISP might.

Comment: Do you have speed issues with normal web browsing? There could be a bug in the driver of your network card...

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu itself does not limit connections. I have run the Deluge BitTorrent client and had around 1000 connections going simultaneously (on a good torrent).

It is possible that Vuze/Azurues might have a setting somewhere for throttling the numbers of connections (probably in the same place as bandwidth settings).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the [TCP half-open connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) limit which Windows suffers. Linux doesn't have such limit. In fact, due the nature of Linux, which is UNIX-like, and characteristics of server; a hard limit to the amount of any connection is a flaw. Now, there are limits that can be configured easily, like the maximum amount of guaranteed sockets:

```
➜  sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
➜  sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
```

What says these numbers? Umm... that Linux guarantee (61000-32768)/60 sockets at the same time, is a total of 470, now, these are not important for torrent connections. In fact you can have 1000 connections with this configuration. Chrome at any moment has 30 active and open sockets. You can have several services using the internet and possibly never reach this limit (services as client transfers, etc., things you use in a desktop). There are other limits but none is directly relevant to torrents.

So, does Ubuntu limit connections? Yes, but is not something you have to be concerned with.